# Only one spark-submit allowed to run in spark-yarn cluster environment

Tags: apache-spark, resources, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing

I set up a spark-yarn cluster environment, the Spark(2.2.0) is in Windows 7; yarn cluster is hadoop 2.7.3.

I run "spark-shell" to use SparkSQL:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs://hadoop_273_namenode_ip:namenode_port/spark-archive.zip
```

Everything is OK by now, but when I start another "spark-shell", the message below seems never ends output to the console:

```
17/10/17 17:33:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1508232101640_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

The application status in the ResourceManager web UI shows

```
[application status] ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM
```

If I close the first the "spark-shell",  the second one get well to work.

It seems that it does not allow multiple spark-shell(spark-submit) at the same time (in my environment).

How to break the limitation?

Comment: It could be that the first job takes up all the available resources. Hence, the second job needs to wait for some to be free before running.

Answer (score 1):

> waiting for AM container to be allocated

It's a resouce limitation, so you could make your first jb consume less resources.

What happens is that the first job consumes all available resources, and by the time the second job comes around, nothing is been free'd, thus the second job has to wait for resources to become available.

That's why, when you close the first shell, the other one will launch.

Comment: Thannks @gsamaras, I tried with more powerful machine (16 vcpus, 112 GB memory)  comparing to the previous one I used (8 vcpus, 28 GB memory), but no effect. and try to change some settings for yarn, still not working. One thing to mention is my yarn environment is deployed in Pseudo Distributed Mode, do you think whether is it the cause for my problem?